# An experiment in quantum theory involving a metal ring

Tags: experimental-physics

I'm trying to remember the name of an experiment that I saw on YaleCourses in a lecture by Professor Shankar. My recollection is that something was sent around a closed metal ring.

The fact that the ring was closed and the function periodic gave rise to the idea that frequency must be quantized, i.e. there is a discrete set of possible frequencies as opposed to an infinite continuum of possible frequencies.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux_quantum - London effect, Little-Parks effect, Josephson effect?

Comment: In which course did you see this. Fundamentals of physics 1,2 or 3?

Comment: @alejandro123 I don't remember.

Comment: Aharonov–Bohm effect?